# How to build react app with its environment variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application that utilizes environment variables. I need to build this React app along with its environment variables because I am unable to set these variables during runtime. The reason is that I am rendering the built React application using ReactDOM within an Angular application.

Inside the react package.json file, the scripts section looks like this:

```
"build": "env-cmd -f ./.env.development.js microbundle-crl --compress --format modern,cjs --jsxFragment React.Fragment"
```

Based on other solutions, I added `react-error-overlay` (versions 6.0.10 and 6.0.9) and `react-scripts` (versions 4.0.3, 4.0.1, and 5.0.0). I attempted the following configuration:

```
"overrides": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.10"
},
"resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.10"
}
```

None of the above solutions worked for me. However, when I hardcode the environment variables, it works as expected.

The environment file looks as follows:

```
const version = require('./package.json').version

module.exports = {
  AP_URL: 'http://localhost:10500'
}
```

Comment: Are your environment variables prepended by `REACT_APP`? As per the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) injection of any other variable will be ignored (except for `NODE_ENV` variables)

Comment: Yes, the environment variables are utilized within the React application, and I am exploring ways to build the React app alongside its environment variables. These variables need to be read from a separate environment variable file. I attempted using the env-cmd library, but it did not work as expected.

Comment: Could you please share a sample or mimic of your environment variables file?

Comment: added my environment file and edit above question.

Comment: How did you create the react app? Was it done manually, with next, CRA, etc?

Comment: @heshjse thank you for adding the sample, with regards to the first comment I don't see the variable named like `REACT_APP_AP_URL` is it a mistake or is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Your env files should be dot text files, not javascript

You can follow this example

```
"build:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development build",
"build:local": "env-cmd -f .env build",
"build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production build",
```

.env.development

```
REACT_APP_NAME='User dashboard'
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://test.com
```

Example how to use your env variable in code

```
object = {...anyProps, url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL};
```

Comment: _env-cmd_ docs **do allow** environment variables to be loaded asynchronously from a _.js_ file

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work using only `env-cmd` on a minimal reproducible example:

App.js

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          {`${
            process.env.REACT_APP_ENVVAR || "Environment variable not defined"
          }`}
        </p>
        <p>
          {`${process.env.IGNORED_VAR || "Environment variable 2 not defined"}`}
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

environment.js

```
module.exports = {
    REACT_APP_ENVVAR: "Environment variable set",
    IGNORED_VAR: "Environment variable 2 set"
}
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f ./environment.js react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f ./environment.js react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

If you use these code samples on a basic `create-react-app` project you can see that the environment variable named `IGNORED_VAR` gets ignored in the build simply because it doesn't start with `REACT_APP`. **This is a safety measure to prevent injecting unrelated variables in builds** as stated in the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

It seems to me that the variable names in your environment file are not prepended by `REACT_APP` and, if I am not mistaken, your build script is missing the `build` command.